# Apple DeviceCheck APIs maximum number of requests per minute

Tags: ios, tvos

Does anybody know the request limits of Apple DeviceCheck API to get per-device data?

In the documentation, it is mentioned HTTP error 429 will be thrown for too many requests, but there is no information about maximum number of request per min/hour.

Apple Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/accessing_and_modifying_per_device_data

Comment: I too am wondering this - not ideal for something that is basically a security check to not have this information!

Answer (score 0):

According to this doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns), error 429 is "The server received too many requests for the same device token".

Now that is for push notifications to APN, not DeviceCheck. The link you provided says error 429 is "Too many requests were sent to the server".

So assuming "Too many requests were sent to the server" means the same as "The server received too many requests for the same device token", the request limit is for the client and not your own server, so you should be fine.

Based on your testings, does it seem like this assumption is correct?